# Pandas merge dataframe with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Suppose that I have df1 and df2 that looks like this:

```
    df1:
           start  end group
    index                  
    a          1    3     x
    a          3    6     x
    a          6    9     z
    b          1    7     y
    b          7   15     x
    b         15   17     y
    c          1    4     z
    c          4    9     z
    c          9   15     z
        
    df2:
           value
    index       
    a        1.0
    a        4.8
    a        7.0
    b        2.0
    b        5.0
    b        6.0
    c        2.0
    c        3.0
    c       14.0
```

I want to make a new column in df2 called group and assign it by condition that refers df2.value to df1.start and df1.end such as:

```
if df2.value >= df1.start and df2.value < df1.end:
    df2.group = df1.group
```

So in index 'a' for example, range 1-3=x; 3-6=x; 6-9=z, in index 'b', range 1-7=y; 7-15=x; 15-17=y, and in index 'c', range 1-4=z; 4-9=z; 9-15=z

so the results will be like this:

```
df2:
       value group
index             
a        1.0     x
a        4.8     x
a        7.0     z
b        2.0     y
b        5.0     y
b        6.0     y
c        2.0     z
c        3.0     z
c       14.0     z
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Datanovice in this case the condition is unique for every index. example in index a: 1-3=x; 3-6=x; 6-9=z

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, both the dataframes have equal length, you can achieve this easily with np.where

```
np.where((df2.value>=df1.start) & (df2.value<df1.end), df2.group=df1.group, df2.group=0)
```

This evaluates your condition, and if it is False, df2.group is set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
list_in = []
for i in range(0, df2.shape[0]):
    if df1.iloc[i]['start']<=df2.iloc[i]['value']<df1.iloc[i]['end']:
        list_in.append(df1.iloc[i]['group'])
    else:
        list_in.append('Nan')
df2 = df2.assign(group = list_in)
```

Comment: this loop only evaluate by the start and end of individual rows so in df2.iloc[4]['group] it returns NaN instead of 'y'

Comment: Yes, since df2.iloc[4]['group'] is not greater than df1.iloc[4]['group'] it should be nan. This is what I understood from the question.

Comment: I edit the question for more clarity